# CoreGraphics in iOS: how can I save the paths drawn in a CGContext and retrieve them in the next draw call?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, cgcontext, cgcontextdrawpath

EDIT:

What I am trying to achieve is skip the call to firstDraw() the second time that drawRect is called. Reason for this is that in my real code I have got a lot of data points and lines to draw, so I thought thata if I recycle the previously drawn things I could optimize the performance. Is this possible at all with CoreGraphics?

---

I'd like to be able to perform multiple drawings on a UIView without having to re-draw what I have already drawn.

The code below will execute two draws at a time distance of 2.4 seconds. After the first call I use **CGContextSaveGState** to save the state. In the second call I retrieve the current graphic context and then add some lines. However this seem to fail as it appears that the previous context is lost.

---

**What I get:**

Here is what I get at the **first** draw call:

[image]

Here is what I get after the **second** call:

[image]

This instead is what I **would like to get** instead after the second call:

[image]

---

**Here is the code:**

```
import UIKit

class GraphView: UIView {

    var count : Int = 0

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        if ( count == 0){
            firstDraw()
         NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.4, target: self, selector: "setNeedsDisplay", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            count++
        }
        else{
            addLinesToDraw()
        }
    }

    func firstDraw(){
        // Drawing code
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50, 50);

        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 60, 60);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 150, 150);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 110, 90);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        // Draw a Point as a small square
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
        //NSLog(@"Drawing rect at point [x: %i, y: %i]", xPosition+resolution, pressureIntValue);
        CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10));
        CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10));
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        CGContextSaveGState(context)
    }

    func addLinesToDraw(){
        // Drawing code
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 30, 60);

        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 20);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 120, 250);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 110, 90);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        // Draw a Point as a small square
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
        //NSLog(@"Drawing rect at point [x: %i, y: %i]", xPosition+resolution, pressureIntValue);
        CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(20, 30, 10, 10));
        CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(20, 30, 10, 10));
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        CGContextSaveGState(context)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `drawRect:`, you have to draw everything from scratch.  So, in your case, you want to change your code to something like:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    firstDraw()

    if ( count == 0){
     NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.4, target: self, selector: "setNeedsDisplay", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        count++
    }
    else{
        addLinesToDraw()
    }
}
```

If you don't like this solution, you could always do all your drawing in a separate CGContext and blit it to the screen in your `drawRect` method.

Comment: Ok. What I am trying to achieve is skip the call to firstDraw() the second time that drawRect is called. Reason for this is that in my real code I have got a lot of data points and lines to draw, so I thought thata if I recycle the previously drawn things I could optimize the performance. Is this possible at all with CoreGraphics?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIGraphicsPushContext(context)` instead of `CGContextSaveGState(context)` to make your context the current drawing context.
Difference described here: [CGContextSaveGState vs UIGraphicsPushContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505871/cgcontextsavegstate-vs-uigraphicspushcontext)